# Google Clould Build Test Automation error with “node” is incompatible with this module

Tags: unit-testing, docker, kubernetes, continuous-integration

I'm spending two days because of this trouble.

I have Cloud Build setting already but am trying to insert `test process` into Cloud build on GCP.

so, here's what I've added,

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/yarn
  args: ['install']
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/yarn
  args: ['test:unit']
```

but I got an error `error @grpc/grpc-js@0.6.9: The engine “node” is incompatible with this module. Expected version “8.13.0 || >=10.10.0”.
error Found incompatible module`

I don't seriously know why it happened. Do I have to install node at the previous step? Or just sync the node engine version? If yes, how do I set node engine version?

I've already done `--ignore-engines` at install but even the error is occurred when testing...

What points am I missing? and how can I figure it out?

Comment: With npm it have a same result.

Answer (score 1):

```
- name: node:10.15.1
  entrypoint: yarn
  args: ['install']
```

I solved that with this one.